# Total Variation Distance between two uniform distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, total-variation

Two distributions with $P=Unif([0,s])$ and $Q=Unif([0,t])$ where $0<s<t$

I have the general formula and use the uniform pdf for P and Q
$$TV(P,Q) = 1/2 \int_{x\in E} |p_{\theta}-p_{\theta'}| dx$$
$$= 1/2 \int_{x\in E} |\frac{1}{s}-\frac{1}{t}| dx$$

Now I am having trouble with integrating. Which space do I integrate on, from s to t, since we want the distance of the two pdfs? And if so, how do I proceed?

Comment: Here's the answer too: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/398393/total-variation-distance-uniform-distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $\frac 1 2 \int_0^{s} |\frac  1s -\frac  1t|dx+\frac 1 2\int_s^{t} \frac 1 t dx$.

Comment: So the area from 0 to s using both pdfs (P&Q) and then just the area from s to t for the single pdf (Q). Thanks

Comment: @Le_Poisson - Between $s$ and $t$ it is still the difference between the two densities but one of the densities is $0$